# Не отображается русский язык в email шаблоне полученном через Thymeleaf в Spring

Tags: spring, email, thymeleaf

Возникла проблема с шаблоном на Thymeleaf при отправке письма по email. Когда приходит письмо на почту, там вместо русских букв знаки вопросов.

```
private void sendMessage(User user){
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) {

            Context ctx = new Context();

            ctx.setVariable("name", user.getUsername());
            ctx.setVariable("activationCode", user.getActivationCode());

            String htmlMessage = templateEngine.process("email/activationCode", ctx);

            mailSender.send(user.getEmail(), "активация электронной почты", htmlMessage);
        }
    }
```

MailSender.send:

```
public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String htmlMessage) {

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);

                message.setFrom(mailUsername);
                message.setTo(emailTo);                
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setText(htmlMessage, true);

            }

        };

        try {

            mailSender.send(preparator);

        }
        catch (MailException ex) {

            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

Вот сам шаблон html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  

    <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
            xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <title>Title</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <p th:text="'Здравствуйте, ' + ${name} + '!'"></p>
        <p>Добро пожаловать! Для активации вашей электронной почты перейдите по ссылке: </p><a th:href="@{'http://localhost:8080/activate/' + ${activationCode}}">Код активации</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

С шаблонами для мэппинга все нормально, а с этим шаблоном какая то проблема.

В свойствах файла html стоит utf-8 так же как и всех работающих шаблонов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При чем проблема в теле письма, а заголовок нормально отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделал отправку сообщения так, чтобы можно было при отправке дополнительно указать кодировку содержимого UTF-8. Все заработало:

```
public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String htmlMessage) {

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException {

                mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailUsername));
                mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailTo));
                mimeMessage.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");   
                mimeMessage.setContent(htmlMessage, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

            }

        };

        try {

            mailSender.send(preparator);

        }
        catch (Throwable mEx) {

            System.err.println(mEx.getMessage());

        }

    }
```